# Changing Cntl+Click to Cntl+Shift+Click in Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, productivity-power-tools

Is there a way to change the Cntl+Click Goto Definition in Productivity Power Tools to use a different key combination. It is nearly impossible to copy and past with that enabled.  I keep going to the definition.

Comment: Let go of the control key between copy and paste? :)

Comment: I'd rather not have to learn a completely knew behavior. Lol